# need to find a good editor for mac

Tags: editors

Can someone please suggest a good latex editor for mac. something close to one that is used in this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzB8YcuGw4w

I liked the highlight and everything that this editor is offering. right now I am using TeXworks and it is so very plain

Thanks for the help

Comment: [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256306) TeXstudio might be something you like.

Comment: The editor is `WinEdt` (v.7 at the time of the video, but v. 9.1 today). I've heard it works on Mac using` Wine`. It's shareware.

Comment: Straight dupe: there is no one true editor, it's a personal judgement. On the Mac TeXshop is very popular but there are lots of other choices, both TeX-specific editors and more general ones.

Comment: thank you for helpful comments…...trying TeXmaker for the time being ….